# Salesforce field level access determined by third variable

Tags: salesforce

For the contacts object, I have a custom checkbox which represents whether the contact owner wants the contact information (email and phone) to be visible. Most of our contacts will be completely visible to everyone. However, for a few contacts, we want them to be visible but their contact information needs to be hidden to everyone except for the owner.

Is there a way to set field-level access dependent on another variable? Could you create a workflow to redirect to another page layout if the contact information is visible? If so, can you restrict objects to certain field layouts depending on whether or not you are the record owner? And would would the contact information for "hidden contacts" still show up in reports?

Answer (score 0):

Redirects, custom Visualforce view page etc hacks are all nice and shiny until you realize people will be able to pull data they want via some reports, list views, Outlook integration, mobile apps etc ;)

There's no straightforward answer because field visibility is really "all or nothing" (by Profiles & Permission Sets). Owner/Role-related stuff will help you only if you'd store data in some new related objects.

Another option - Store public part in Leads (public read only for example) and sensitive part - in Contacts (private)? Some lookup to link the 2, maybe a trigger when new Contact is created and you're good to go.

Last but not least - have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/777/can-i-grant-different-field-level-security-based-on-record-ownership for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly (My english...) You could create a new RecordType and a new customized page layout without this fields assigned to it, then you have to create a WFR that change the Recordtype when the cheked field becomes true.

I'm assuming that you know how you have to give permissions to this new Recordtype...etc

Hope this helps.